# How to get the amount of selected files in automator

Tags: automator

I created a workflow to move items from one folder to another and I want to get a notification when it's done. I could create the workflow without problems but now I would like to show the number of moved files on the notification pop-up.

How can I get the number of files?

Basically I'm copying downloaded files to a "Downloads" folder on iCloud Drive. After the files are copied, I would like to show a notification saying "{NumberOfFiles} moved successfully."

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your workflow?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like Apple Script (as action in Automator) that counts the files and displays the result in Notification ?

Comment: That could be, but I don't know how to create the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Apple Script to set a variable (named `item_count`) to the number of items returned from the previous action:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set (value of variable "item_count" of front workflow) to (count of input)
    return input
end run
```

The list of items is simply passed through.

You could use it like this:

[image]

Comment: This nice, but missing the part how to show the result in the notification pop-up

Comment: @Buscar웃: uhm. how do you mean?

Comment: Thanks! I guess that I just need to add the item_count variable to the displayed text on notification pop-up and it's done. I will try and let you know. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the way Automator handles variables in Apple scripts has changed since @hop answered in '14, but setting the `item_count` variable as an action seems to work better.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return count of input
end run
```

[image: Count number of items in Automator with AppleScript.]